# Use of the indefinite article instead of the definite one before the nouns derived from verbs

Tags: articles

I was watching [Crash Course Astronomy](https://youtu.be/I82ADyJC7wE) and I came across a sentence with the use of the indefinite article that I am confused with. ( It is at around [5:00](https://youtu.be/I82ADyJC7wE?t=5m)). Here is the sentence:

> Galaxies probably formed from huge clouds of gas billions of years ago. As a cloud collapses, small eddies in the gas would get amplified, and would create an overall spin. This naturally leads to a **flattening** of the cloud.

Why was the indefinite article used before the word *flattening* instead of *the*? Does *a* mean that it leads to some flattening? if not, then would it be correct to use *the* in there?

Comment: It's because it's a general statement: This leads to a flattening of the cloud. The flattening of cloud 567A occurred in the last 100 years. [That is invented but it shows how **a** makes a general statement, and then becomes **the**.] Cars engine trouble can signal a huge expense. [general]. The expense [specific] might be due to A, B and C.

Comment: Also "a flattening" implies a degree of flattening, where "the flattening" implies completeness.  Another example would be "melting ice causes a rise in tide; the rise can vary from one to two feet".

Comment: @Doarn it is a or the because of: of the cloud. It's a "genitive".